# Capture screenshot of a running video

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have a video which I am playing using MPMoviePlayerViewController,I want to capture screenshot after every 1 sec as I want to perform some action on the individual present on the captured Image.

I am using the following code for capturing screenshot----

```
 CGRect   contectRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024,768);
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(1024,768));

[_player.moviePlayer.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
NSLog(@"view size %f %f",viewImage.size.width,viewImage.size.height);
UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
CGImageRef imageRef1 = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([viewImage CGImage], contectRect);
UIImage   *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef1 scale:1.0orientation:viewImage.imageOrientation];
```

But in this I am always getting a black image.

I know there is another way of getting image from video ie following but I dont want to use these images as these images do not fit in my requirements.

```
    AVAsset *asset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:path]];
    AVAssetImageGenerator *imageGenerator = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc]initWithAsset:asset];
    CMTime time = CMTimeMake(1, 1);
    UIImage *thumbnail = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[imageGenerator copyCGImageAtTime:time actualTime:NULL error:NULL]];
    [UIImagePNGRepresentation(thumbnail) writeToFile:imgName atomically:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to capture thumbnail of the video. And try to set that.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8906104/2515572).

```
-(void)generateImage
{
    AVURLAsset *asset=[[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:self.url options:nil];
    AVAssetImageGenerator *generator = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
    generator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform=TRUE;
    [asset release];
    CMTime thumbTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0,30);

    AVAssetImageGeneratorCompletionHandler handler = ^(CMTime requestedTime, CGImageRef im, CMTime actualTime, AVAssetImageGeneratorResult result, NSError *error){
        if (result != AVAssetImageGeneratorSucceeded) {
            NSLog(@"couldn't generate thumbnail, error:%@", error);
        }
        [button setImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:im] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        thumbImg=[[UIImage imageWithCGImage:im] retain];
        [generator release];
    };

    CGSize maxSize = CGSizeMake(320, 180);
    generator.maximumSize = maxSize;
    [generator generateCGImagesAsynchronouslyForTimes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSValue valueWithCMTime:thumbTime]] completionHandler:handler];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do have an option to asynchronously request thumbnail images from an MPMoviePlayer:

```
requestThumbnailImagesAtTimes:timeOption:
```

But this is a very expensive operation, and there's a good chance you'll find it too slow to do much in "real-time"

Depending on your ultimate objective, you may find some far more robust tools [in the GPUImage Library](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) especially since the individual frame buffers are readily exposed to you as CGImageRef objects, which you can periodically sample.

Answer (score 0):

Use `NSTimer` and perform your action accordingly:--

```
    NSTimer *tm1= [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 //here it is 1 seconds
                                          target:self
                                        selector:@selector(yourMethod:)
                                        userInfo:nil
                                         repeats:NO];

-(void)yourMethod:(NSTimer*)timer
{
//your code
}
```