# how to capture the thumnail of the video in UIImagePickerController in iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

I am capturing the thumnail of video it work fine but problem is that it capture the thumbnail in horizontal mode but i want in vertical mode any idea how to fix this issue.

here is the code for thumbnail.

```
    AVAsset *asset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:movieURL];// url= give your url video here
    AVAssetImageGenerator *imageGenerator = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc]initWithAsset:asset];
    CMTime time = CMTimeMake(1, 5);//it will create the thumbnail after the 5 sec of video 
    CGImageRef imageRef = [imageGenerator copyCGImageAtTime:time actualTime:NULL error:NULL];
    UIImage *thumbnail = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    thumbnailImageView.image=thumbnail;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Thumbnail image of video](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8906004/thumbnail-image-of-video)

Comment: @Pepe i am not asking how to create thumbnail i am asking thumbnail is created in horizontal mode i want in vertical mode

Comment: If you create your collectionView with xib then select collection view scroll direction vertical.....

Answer (score 0):

Get rotated image using following code, and use final image

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(thumbnail.size);//thumbnail is your original image
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextRotateCTM (context, radians(90));//set rotation as per your requirement
[thumbnail drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
UIImage *finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();//image after rotation
```