# How to get frame from video on iOS

Tags: ios, video, avasset

In my app I want to take frames from a video for filtering them. I try to take frame frim video by time offset. This is my code:

```
- (UIImage*)getVideoFrameForTime:(NSDate*)time {

    CGImageRef thumbnailImageRef = NULL;

    NSError *igError = nil;

    NSTimeInterval timeinterval = [time timeIntervalSinceDate:self.videoFilterStart];

    CMTime atTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(timeinterval, 1000);
    thumbnailImageRef =
    [self.assetImageGenerator copyCGImageAtTime:atTime
                                     actualTime:NULL
                                          error:&igError];

    if (!thumbnailImageRef) {
        NSLog(@"thumbnailImageGenerationError %@", igError );
    }

    UIImage *image = thumbnailImageRef ? [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:thumbnailImageRef] : nil;

    return image;
}
```

Unfortunately, I see only frames which located on integer seconds: 1, 2, 3.. Even when time interval is non-integer (1.5, etc).

How to get frames at any non-integer interval?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grab frames from video using Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32286320/grab-frames-from-video-using-swift)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thnx to @shallowThought I found an answer in this question [Grab frames from video using Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32286320/grab-frames-from-video-using-swift)

You just need to add this two lines

```
assetImgGenerate.requestedTimeToleranceAfter = kCMTimeZero;
assetImgGenerate.requestedTimeToleranceBefore = kCMTimeZero;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this project to get more frame details
The corresponding project on github: [iFrameExtractor.git](http://git://github.com/lajos/iFrameExtractor.git)

Comment: thnx a lot, i will check it.

Comment: you have check the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly NSDate's accuracy only goes up to the second which explains why frames are only take on integer seconds. You'll have to use a different type of input to get frames at non-integer seconds.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I logged timeinterval and it is float. Also, If create CMTime like this `CMTime atTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(3, 1000);` and change 3 to 3.5 result will be the same.

Comment: What happens if you do `CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(3, 1)` and `CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(3.5, 1)`

Comment: I will see two equal frames