# convert mp4/video file into frames using objective c in ios

Tags: ios, video, frame

i need to create an app in which i have to breck video/mp4 files in to image frames.Please provide me any solution create different image frames from video files in iOS app.

Comment: There are lots of solutions availble try search see this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4199879/iphone-read-uiimage-frames-from-video-with-avfoundation

Answer (score 2):

```
MPMoviePlayerController *movie = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"yourvideofilename.mp4"]];//replace your video file name

UIImage *singleFrameImage = [movie thumbnailImageAtTime:10   timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionExact];
```

Try this above lines of code, i hope you got the result